# Keras - How does to get misclassifcation?

Tags: keras

I have implemented a neural network by Keras, and I have used `loss='binary_crossentropy'` to get model's loss and accuracy. Now I would to get the misclassification error, but I don't know how to set the *loss* parameter in `model.compile()` to obtain this kind of evaluation.
I don't have found anything about it on the Keras website [keras.io](https://keras.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `metrics` parameter in `model.compile()`. A metric is a function that is used to judge the performance of your model, like in your case classification error, but not used for training. Check more [here](https://keras.io/metrics/).

In your case you can use: `model.compile(..., loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics='binary_accuracy')`

If you are doing classification you should use: `model.compile(..., loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='categorical_accuracy')`

Comment: Is it possible to get and plot `binary_accuracy` and `accuracy` together?

Comment: Yes you can pass them as a list ` metrics=['accuracy', 'binary_accuracy']`. For plotting if you are using tensorflow backend then you can use tensorboard (https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) callback to plot all of em. Else you can write a custom callback of your own.